# Text blocks positions and sizes detection in command line mode in tesseract

Tags: ocr, command-line-arguments, textblock, tesseract

[tesseract  OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) have a command line interface, which allow us to recognize text from images with some parameters.

Input argumetns are **imagename** (path to image) **outputbase** (name of recognized text) and **-psm pagesegmode** parameters.

```
pagesegmode values are:
 0 = Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
 1 = Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
 2 = Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR
 3 = Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
 4 = Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
 5 = Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
 6 = Assume a single uniform block of text.
 7 = Treat the image as a single text line.
 8 = Treat the image as a single word.
 9 = Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10 = Treat the image as a single character.
-l lang and/or -psm pagesegmode must occur before anyconfigfile.
```

But can it library write positions and sizes of recognized text blocks to the specific file or it is an internal information?

Comment: https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/11/15/tesseract-page-segmentation-modes-psms-explained-how-to-improve-your-ocr-accuracy/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tesseract 3.0x supports a "hocr" command option, which produces a HTML-format output file consisting of recognized words and their coordinates. It does not have size/font info, though.

Comment: Thank you very much!
This is all what I need.