# Best way to extract word or phrase region on image from point for it's further recognition?

Tags: image, image-processing, cpu-word, ocr, crop

The solution must be universal (working with different fonts and colors) and stable.

Input data is point with X, Y coordinates and output data is rectangle or more comples shape, which contains word or phrase.

[image: Image with input point (red) and output rectange(blue)]

Now i am using tesseract recognition of entire image with [**hocr**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962160/text-blocks-positions-and-sizes-detection-in-command-line-mode-in-tesseract) option, then extract all rectangles from output html and finally find the nearest to point reactangle. Code shown below.
But it's inefficiently, beacuse of entire image recognition.

Off course, it's possible to recognize not entire image, but part, but it's not a clear solution too, because of different font sizes and useless words recognitions all the same.

**UPDATE**

```cs
public class WordRecognizerTesseractHocr
{
    const string HelperFileName = "temp";

    public string NextVariant()
    {
        Bitmap.Save(HelperFileName + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
        var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("tesseract.exe", HelperFileName + ".png temp hocr");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        var result = GetNearestWord(File.ReadAllText(HelperFileName + ".html"), Position);

        return result;
    }

    public string GetNearestWord(string tesseractHtml, Point position)
    {
        var xml = XDocument.Parse(tesseractHtml);

        RectsWords = new Dictionary<Rectangle, string>();

        var ocr_words = xml.Descendants("span").Where(element => element.Attribute("class").Value == "ocr_word").ToList();
        foreach (var ocr_word in ocr_words)
        {
            var strs = ocr_word.Attribute("title").Value.Split(' ');
            int left = int.Parse(strs[1]);
            int top = int.Parse(strs[2]);
            int width = int.Parse(strs[3]) - left + 1;
            int height = int.Parse(strs[4]) - top + 1;
            RectsWords.Add(new Rectangle(left, top, width, height), ocr_word.Value);
        }

        var nearestWords = RectsWords.OrderBy(rectWord => Distance(position, rectWord.Key));

        return nearestWords.Count() != 0 ? nearestWords.First().Value : string.Empty;
    }

    public static double Distance(Point pos, Rectangle rect)
    {
        if (pos.X < rect.Left)
        {
            if (pos.Y < rect.Top)
                return Math.Sqrt((rect.X - pos.X) * (rect.X - pos.X) + (rect.Top - pos.Y) * (rect.Top - pos.Y));
            else if (pos.Y < rect.Top + rect.Height)
                return rect.Left - pos.X;
            else
                return Math.Sqrt((rect.X - pos.X) * (rect.X - pos.X) + 
                    (rect.Top + rect.Height - 1 - pos.Y) * (rect.Top + rect.Height - 1 - pos.Y));
        }
        else if (pos.X < rect.Left + rect.Width)
        {
            if (pos.Y < rect.Top)
                return rect.Top - pos.Y;
            else if (pos.Y < rect.Top + rect.Height)
                return 0;
            else
                return pos.Y - (rect.Top + rect.Height - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            if (pos.Y < rect.Top)
                return Math.Sqrt((rect.X + rect.Width - 1 - pos.X) * (rect.X + rect.Width - 1 - pos.X) + 
                    (rect.Top - pos.Y) * (rect.Top - pos.Y));
            else if (pos.Y < rect.Top + rect.Height)
                return pos.X - (rect.Left + rect.Width - 1);
            else
                return Math.Sqrt((rect.X + rect.Width - 1 - pos.X) * (rect.X + rect.Width - 1 - pos.X) +
                    (rect.Top + rect.Height - 1 - pos.Y) * (rect.Top + rect.Height - 1 - pos.Y));
        }
    }

    public IDictionary<Rectangle, string> RectsWords
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that may work. It should be pretty fast, but it's likely to be easily hurt by noise.

First get a deskewed image of the text, in whatever format is easiest for you to work in.

Next, get the point you care about in x,y.

Starting from the y cooridnate, look at full rows up and down until you see several fully empty rows. These will mark the top and bottom of the row of text for the point you specified. These are the bounds of the word rectangle in y.

Repeat the same thing for x, but look for columns to get the bounds of the word rectangle in x.

Now you should have the bounds for the whole word, and you can easily get the word from that.